# List items parse displaying the same String onClick (PutExtra)

Tags: android

I am trying to transfer my username value to a new activity. However when I do this it is displaying the first array item I have added, for example the code below displays "Bob Jones" for the username in the Conversation activity even if I click on a different item in the list.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
TextView user;
TextView threadId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //messaging_string = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messaging_string);


    //this.GetActivityFeedData();

    final ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.messagingListView);
    final ActivityAdapter itemAdapter = new ActivityAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this.GetActivityFeedData());

    listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messaging_username);
            threadId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messaging_threadId);
            listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConversationView.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", user.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("pos", position);
            intent.putExtra("threadId", threadId.getText().toString());


            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}



public ArrayList<MessageItem> GetActivityFeedData() {
    ArrayList<MessageItem> items = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();


    items.add(new MessageItem(6, "Lorna Smith", "image", DateTime.now(), "Hello what are you doing"));


    return items;
}


class ActivityFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    ArrayList<MessageItem> recentTracks;




    //remove to not loading more data


}


public class ActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessageItem> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<MessageItem> items;
    private int currentPage = 0;

    public ActivityAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessageItem> recentTrackArrayList) {
        super(context, 0, recentTrackArrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = recentTrackArrayList;
    }



     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to fetch the content of the row you clicked. You can retrieve this object with `parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`,

```
MessageItem itemAtPostion = (MessageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConversationView.class);
intent.putExtra("username", itemAtPostion.Username);
intent.putExtra("pos", position);
intent.putExtra("threadId", itemAtPostion.ThreadId);
```

Comment: Thank you that works great for my Username... With the threadId its not working - It is an integer could this be why? I have uploaded my MessageItem in which ThreadId is an integer.

Comment: yes it is. Use `String.valueOf(itemAtPostion.ThreadId)`, if you need the String in the other activity